# GPG-Gmail integration?

Tags: gmail, gnupg

Is there any solution to integrate GPG with GMail? FireGPG has been [discontinued](http://blog.getfiregpg.org/2010/06/07/firegpg-discontinued/) and the last version did not support GMail.

Encrypting the email offline with GPG is very clumsy. It's ok for occasional use, but it's not great for more frequent use.

Answer (score 2):

I know its not really a proper answer to your question, but I've used [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) with Gmail via IMAP with the [Enigmail](http://www.enigmail.net/home/) extension with great success in the past.

Comment: It's what I use for this function! And more secure than the browser plug-ins that kinda-sorta shim this into Firefox.